# How do I get rid of the MissingManifestResourceException in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two assemblies in my application one is where all the code is, the other holds all the images and extra resource files. It was working just fine until I added new images to the resource dll. Now it keeps coming up with MissingManifestResourceException and saying it can't find certain images. All my images are being compiled as Resources.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this problem as right-click the Resources.resx file in the Solution Explorer and click Run Custom Tool. This re-generates the auto-generated Resources.Designer.cs file.

If the .resx file was added to the project manually, the Custom Tool property of the file must be set to "ResXFileCodeGenerator".

Rebuilt that project and then run it

Comment: There is no Resources.resx in this specific library just a bunch of files with their compile property set to Resource. Should I add a Resource.resx?

Comment: could you try to change your build content as "Embedded Resource" and Copy to OutputDirectory "Copy Always". Hope it works.